# Google OCR: Special Characters Affecting OCR Number Recognition

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I've been playing around with Google's OCR recently using the default tutorial and was trying to parse numbers. I've seen previous issues dealing with numbers on license plates, but was wondering if there was a solution when special characters affect the results of OCR. Most notably, including the '#' character with a number, such as #1, #2, etc as shown below results in the output ##Z#T# and even occasionally gives me Chinese characters even after I set the language to/from settings to English.

[Numbers with pound sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fU7x.png)

For a similar comparison, the image below is easily read by the OCR:
[Numbers without pound sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX37R.png)

Is there a setting that I'm missing that can improve the results or is this just a constraint by the model?

Comment: Hm...I can not reproduce the behavior you mentioned through Google Cloud Vision API v1 > vision.images.annotate, and the result I got is "#1 #2 #3 #4\n". Can you re-try and post your request and response?

Comment: Hi JL-HN, it turns out that the I had already applied the fix, there was just some functionality error with redeploying functions on the cloud. For some reason, I have to delete the function and then deploy it every time. Re-deploying doesn't seem to override the predecessor. Thanks!